# SF 3.4 inject bundle config in services

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Using Symfony 3.4, I just try a simple case for a new bundle (name: `APiToolBundle`).

Here is the content of `src/ApiToolBundle/Resources/config/config.yml` :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }

api_tool:
    api_url: %myapi_url%
    api_authorization_name: 'Bearer'
```

This file is loaded by ApiToolBundleExtension :

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

I have set the Configuration file too :

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('production_tool');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('api_url')->defaultValue('')->end()
            ->scalarNode('api_authorization_name')->defaultValue('')->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

But then I just want to bind a config parameter to one of my service :

```
# src/ApiToolBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
ApiToolBundle\Service\MyApi:
  bind:
    $apiUrl: '%api_tool.api_url%'
```

I am based on this doc : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/configuration.html

But I am not sure to understand everything, since they talk about mergin in other way ... Do I need to do something else to load my own bundle config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bit tricky to grasp. The bundle configuration is distinct from the parameters you use in your service configuration (even though inside your config you can also define services, which seems a bit odd at first). This is one of the reasons why Symfony in Version 4 discouraged using the semantic configuration inside applications, not use bundles & configuration, and instead directly work with parameters and services instead.

You will need to map the configuration to parameters or directly inject them into the service where you need them, in case you don't want them to be publicly available to other services or to be pulled from the container using `getParameter`. You can do this in the Extension where you have access to the ContainerBuilder.

See for example the FrameworkExtension where you have large configs that change the container: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.4.30/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L194-L196

In your case it could look something like this:

```php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    # Below is the new part, the rest is copied from your question

    # If you only want to use the configuration values internally in your services:
    $container->getDefinition('ApiToolBundle\Service\MyApi')->setArgument(
        0 # Offset of the argument where you want to use the api url
        $config['api_url']
    );

    # If you want to make the values publicly available as parameters:
    $container->setParameter('api_tool.api_url', $config['api_url']);
}
```

Comment: I am gonna test it tomorrow, but seems so complicated fairly ... Why Symfony 3 didn't automate this process ..

Comment: Ok, seems to work for 1 parameter, but what if my service needs more parameters ? I need to inject an array for example ? which doesn't depend on config but credentials (as an arrya) got from User security entity, seems so heavy.. .Maybe better to only get parameter from container in service ? and don't try to do DI

Comment: Oh wait, if I put my config the main `app/config/config.yml`, seems to be ok, but I can't use the  `config.yml` of the bundle ? I need to define default values only in PHP code ? this seems crazy..

Comment: What do you mean? The config you have in your `app/config/config.yml` is ok. That is where it is supposed to be. Basically `Configuration` tells the user of your bundle what configuration options are available and the `*Extension` class uses this configuration, either by making it publicly available or only using it internally to configure its services. That is why you need the php code. If you don't want to distribute the bundle, e.g. `APpBundle` you can just add the value to `parameters:` instead of using the bundle config.

Comment: The configuration under `api_tool` in your `app/config/config.yml` would otherwise be "meaningless" as Symfony can not tell what is supposed to be happening with it. The only generalized configuration you have is `services:` and `parameters:` which you can use in your `app/config/config.yml`, `app/config/services.yml` or in the bundle's `services.yml` as Symfony understands what these 2 blocks mean and what to do with them. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yeaj I thought there was a kind of way to use a `config.yml` file directly in the bundle. Now I need to find a way to mix injection from DI, and how to pass a classic parameter. Thanks for your time and explanations